# Fix string contraints on JPA entity attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new in JPA,
I want to set only specific fix department names to attribute in entity as a fix string as constraints.I.e default values to attributes.

How to set it?

Comment: Do you mean a field in an entity object with default value? If so, you can just define the field with default value, e.g. `private String name = "fixed name";`

Comment: @TonnyTc , but I have multiple fixed values for the filed and needs match one of them.
e.g status is the filed and multiples values - active , deactive, invalid
I need to set this active , deactive, invalid as a constraints.

Comment: @Lucky you can try using ENUM for those fixed values

Comment: @Lucky Then, do you mean you want a validator to validate if the field's value is one of the predefined values (e.g. "active" , "deactive" or "invalid")? If so, you could create a custom validator as the blog done [How to add validation to your Spring Entities](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2017/05/01/add-validation-spring-entities/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use enumerated as indicated by Dinesh Dontha, try this:

Entity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable(){

    private MyEnum attribute;
}
```

Enum

```
public enum MyEnum {
     

    NAME1("N1") 

    private String shortName;

    private MyEnum(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public static MyEnum fromShortName(String shortName) {
        switch (shortName) {
        case "N1":
            return NacionalidadEnum.NAME1;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ShortName [" + shortName
                    + "] not supported.");
        }
    }
}
```

Converter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MyEntityEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MyEnum myEnum) {
        return myEnum.getShortName();
    }

    @Override
    public MyEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return MyEnum.fromShortName(dbData);
    }

}
```